# find a capital in a string. No loops. Only if statements and string methods python

Tags: python, string

The questions in the title. i have to be able to determine if there is a capital in a raw_input statement. I cant use loops. just if and string methods.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the string?  Can it contain whitespace?  Can it contain numbers?  Other characters?  Is it guaranteed to be ascii?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We are not a "do my homework" forum. Please post a well formed question and your attempt to solve it, so that we can help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No loops - use recursion

```
has_capital = lambda s:s[0].isupper() or has_capital(s[1:]) if s else False
```

Comment: nice one :) way to get around the loops problem ...

Comment: functional programmers would be proud :) (Answer_score++).  Any reason you made this a `lambda` function as opposed to a regular function (which I would expect OP to be more familiar with)?

Comment: @mgilson, that was just the way I first thought of it. Usually I'm the one telling people off for giving names to lambda functions :)

Answer (score 4):

If you convert a string with only lower case letters to a lower case it will match itself. So, the following will give you TRUE for strings with uppercase.

```
mystring.lower() != mystring
```

Comment: If there WERE an uppercase letter, this would be False, which sounds like the opposite of the question.  Clever idea, though.

Comment: @ScottHunter -- correct.  In fact, `has_upper = mystring.lower() != mystring` is definitely the most robust way I can think to do this.

Comment: While I agree with the points that you both mention, the question says "find a capital". To me that means "return a character in the input which is in uppercase". This is why the "no loops" condition confuses me (are list comprehensions considered loops for this exercise?)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, One could argue that `str.lower()` is also loop.

Comment: @gnibbler: touche! I hadn't thought of that

Comment: @gnibbler -- OP specifically says that string methods are allowed.  And, as far as the specification goes, `str.lower()` doesn't *have* to be implemented as a loop.  It could be a recursive function as you've demonstrated above ...

Comment: +1 why didn't i think of that  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using a set intersection operator

```
import string
if set(raw_input()) & set(string.ascii_uppercase):
  # hello
```

Comment: Or by building only 1 set:  `set(raw_input()).intersection(string.ascii_uppercase)`

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda x:x.isupper(),my_string)
```

although under the hood filter will be a loop construct

maybe ...  or

```
set(my_string) - set(my_string.lower())
```

the conversion to set is also looping over all the letters in my_string (at least I think)